# Java - Reading from file and stopping at specific value

Tags: java

The goal is to read from a given file that has strings and integers. The file has the names of fictitious students along with their test scores. Some students have three test scores, some four, and some none at all. The way the program is supposed to stop and process the test scores for the students is when it finds "-1." Once it finds "-1," it's supposed to stop the loop, and process that student's scores. What I can't figure out is how to have the program stop when it runs into "-1."

When I run it right now, all it does is capture the names of all the students, along with their first test score.

```
    //Declare Variables
    String name;
    String grade;
    String inFile;
    String outFile;
    PrintWriter outputFile;
    int score1 = 0;
    int score2 = 0;
    int score3 = 0;
    int score4 = 0;
    int score5 = 0;
    int score6 = 0;

    //Get input file name
    System.out.print("Enter the input filename: ");
    inFile = KB.nextLine();

    File studentsFile = new File(inFile);
    Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(studentsFile);

    //Capture Student Info
    while(scanFile.hasNext()){
        name = scanFile.nextLine();
        if (scanFile.hasNextInt()){
            score1 = scanFile.nextInt();
            System.out.println(name);
            System.out.println(score1);
        }
```

Sample Input File:

```
     Introduction to Programming 1
     John Sweet
     87 76 90 100 -1
     Ali Hassan
     -1
     Willy Nilly
     73 63 74 70 -1
     Juju Smith Jr.
     89 90 78 88 -1
     Karl Kavington III
     90 100 80 70 -1
     Lary Howard Holiday
     80 77 67 67 -1
     Leo Gordon
     56 88 780 77 -1
     Jessy Brown -1
     90 80 88 92 -1
     Mr. Perfect
     100 100 100 100 -1
     Mr. Missing It All
     0 0 0 0 0 0 -1
```

EDIT: The program is supposed to read through one student and their test scores, perform some calculations, write those to an output file, and then repeat itself with the next student. It's to repeat itself until the end of the file.

Comment: Input file example?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to stop reading the file, you could try inside the `while` loop:

`if(score == -1 ){
break;
}`

You can define the scores inside the conditional. Even, ¿what if score is more than 100? in the conditional you can define for example `if(score<0 || score>100)`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the **-1** in a file data line you will need to parse that line to see if it actually exists among the other data values contained on the very same line.

In your case, because a score data line contained within your data file would (possibly) always **end** with a **-1** value should it require processing, you could utilize either the [String#endsWith()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_endswith.htm) method or the [String#split()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm) method. Since data within a text data file is always of String type anyways it just seems natural to use String methods to poll the data.

Yes you can read in data as a numerical data type if the proper Scanner methods are used but I think you should just keep it simple for now and only retrieve everything as String and since you would retrieve everything as String then the appropriate Scanner method to use for checking whether or not there is another file data line to read (for your **while** loop condition) is the [Scanner#hasNextLine()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnextline.htm) method instead of the [Scanner#hasNext()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnext.htm) method. The **Scanner#hasNext()** method is geared more towards retrieving String Tokens (words) rather than entire String lines. With this in mind the following **while** loop condition would be more appropriate:

```
while (scanFile.hasNextLine()) {
    // .... your loop code ....
}
```

> Using the [**String#endsWith()**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_endswith.htm) method in conjunction with the [**String#split()**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm) method:

Because you are seeking specific criteria from each file data line such as ***Student Name***, ***Student Scores***, and in particular **-1** from the end of ***Student Scores*** you can safely use the ***String#endsWith()*** method to see if **-1** is contained on a Scores data line, for example:

```
while (scanFile.hasNextLine()) {
    name = scanFile.nextLine();
    scroresString = scanFile.nextLine();
    if (scroresString.trim().endsWith("-1")) {
        // Do what needs to be done with the data on this line.
    }
}
```

Once you have determined the fact that a **-1** does exist at the end of a Score data line then you can remove that -1 and split the remaining score data into a String Array using the **String#split()** method. If all goes well all the scores for that Student would be contained within a String Array from which you can take each array element, convert it to Integer or Double and do your required calculations (whatever they might be). Doing it this way can also open up the opportunity to check for score data errors since there could ***possibly*** be an entry error within the scores such as an alpha character mixed in with a numerical value.

Here is an overall example of such a mechanism (writing to file is up to you):

```
Scanner KB = new Scanner(System.in);

List<String> noScores = new ArrayList<>();               // Students with No Scores Avbailable
List<String> notReadyForProcessing = new ArrayList<>();  // Students with No -1 attached to end of scores.
List<String> dataError = new ArrayList<>();              // Students With Score Data Errors
String name = "";
String scoresString = "";

//Get input file name
File studentsFile = null;
String inFile = null;
while (studentsFile == null) {
    System.out.print("Enter the input file name (enter q to quit): ");
    inFile = KB.nextLine();
    if (inFile.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
        System.out.println("Bye-Bye");
        System.exit(0);     // End Application
    }
    studentsFile = new File(inFile);
    // Does the supplied file name exist?
    if (!studentsFile.exists() ) {
        // Nope!
        studentsFile = null;
        System.out.println("Can not locate the file specified (" + inFile 
                        + ")! Please try again." + System.lineSeparator());
    }
}
System.out.println();


// Using 'Try With Resouces' so as to auto-close the Scanner reader
try (Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(studentsFile)) {
    //Skip first line in file since it's a Header Line.
    scanFile.nextLine();
    while (scanFile.hasNextLine()) {
        // Read in the Student Name
        name = scanFile.nextLine().trim();
        // Skip blank lines...
        if (name.equals("")) {
            continue;
        }
        /* If a name contains a -1 at the end then it is 
           obviously flagged for some reason. (unless that
           was a typo in the file)  :p   */
        if (name.endsWith("-1")) {
            name = name.replace("-1", "| Name Flagged: -1 (see records file)");
        }

        // Read in the Student's Scores
        scoresString = scanFile.nextLine();
        // If there is just a -1 then the current student has no scores
        if (scoresString.equals("-1")) {
            // Add the Student to the 'No Scores' List
            noScores.add(name + " | " + scoresString);
        }
        // Otherwise, see if -1 is at end of the scores
        else if (scoresString.endsWith("-1")) {
            // YUP!
            /* Calculate Scores Average... 
                   This should realy be done in a method or Class.
                   There are MANY WAYS to simplify this code. The hope is that this will 
                   give you ideas for other possible situations in the future. 
                       ======================================================================  
             */

            // Get rid of the -1 at the end of scores String
            String procScores = scoresString.substring(0, scoresString.lastIndexOf("-1")).trim();
            // Place the Scores into a Integer Array. 
            // First, Split the scores into a String Array since it all starts as string
            String[] strgScoresArray = procScores.split("\\s+");
            // Then convert each array element into Integer data type
            // and sum them.
            double scoreTotal = 0.0d;
            double scoreAverage = 0.0d;
            int validScoreCount = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < strgScoresArray.length; i++) {
                /* Make sure the String numerical value is indeed 
                       a string representation of a Integer or Double
                       numerical value.   */
                if (strgScoresArray[i].matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
                    scoreTotal += Double.parseDouble(strgScoresArray[i]);
                    validScoreCount++;
                }
                else {
                    // Falty data...Save the Student record into the dataError List.
                    dataError.add(name + " | " + scoresString + " | Element In Error: " + strgScoresArray[i]);
                }
            }
            // Calculate the average Score:
            scoreAverage = scoreTotal / validScoreCount;

            // Display the results to Console Window...
            System.out.println("Student Name:\t" + name);
            System.out.println("Student Scores:\t" + procScores);
            System.out.println("Average Score:\t" + scoreAverage
                    + " From '" + validScoreCount + "' Valid Score Results."
                    + System.lineSeparator());
        }
        // Otherwise, Place the current Student into the 
        // 'Not Ready For Processing' List
        else {
            notReadyForProcessing.add(name + " | " + scoresString);
        }
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println();
// Display the other Lists generated (if you like).
System.out.println("Students That Contain No Scores:" + System.lineSeparator()
                + "================================");
if (noScores.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("NONE");
}
else {
    for (int i = 0; i < noScores.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(noScores.get(i));
    }
}

System.out.println();
System.out.println("Students Not Ready For The Averaging Process:" + System.lineSeparator()
        + "=============================================");
if (notReadyForProcessing.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("NONE");
}
else {
    for (int i = 0; i < notReadyForProcessing.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(notReadyForProcessing.get(i));
    }
}

System.out.println();
System.out.println("Students Records With Score Data Errors:" + System.lineSeparator()
        + "========================================");
if (dataError.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("NONE");
}
else {
    for (int i = 0; i < dataError.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(dataError.get(i));
    }
}
```